How can I fix AWS Elastic Beanstalk error
I deployed Node.js project to the AWS Elastic Beanstalk. I created the user and role in the IAM.
Role is aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role and it has these following policies:
[ AdministratorAccess, AmazonS3FullAccess, AWSElasticBeanstalkMulticontainerDocker, AWSElasticBeanstalkWebTier, AWSElasticBeanstalkWorkerTier ]
User also has these polices as well.
And added this role to the EC2 instance profile.
Here are the env properties
:AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_REGION, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, MONGO_URI, S3_BUCKET_NAME, SECRET_KEY
After I created environment, there was a warning, here is the link.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hnvHenrGhbQbJXtjYlK1rNCN0Mn7z03l/view?usp=drive_link
Health is degraded.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
